# Gmagick extension causing apache to endless restart

Tags: php, apache, php-extension, gmagick

I compiled a Gmagick php7 extension on windows. It works fine in cli mode. But when I enable the extension and start httpd, apache seems to enter an endless loop of restarting. There is no error log, Apache just start and stop again and again.

How I can debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally recompiled the GraphicsMagick in static mode and recompiled the php extension, the question is gone. But I'm still wondering what was going wrong with the shared model GraphicsMagick.